# In Connection.php line 664: could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04, vps

I just installed a LEMP stack on my VPS and hosted my laravel app on it. After running php artisan migrate i get the following error.

```
In Connection.php line 664:

could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where
table_schema = mamaput and table_name = migrations)


In Connector.php line 67:

could not find driver
```

I have PHP version 7.2 and laravel 5.5. What do i need to do?

Comment: Make sure that you have enabled mysql extension in your php configuration (php.ini).

Comment: You need to install/enable pdo_mysql or mysqlnd to/in your system